# Jira: how to record customers who experienced an issue?

Tags: jira

A customer experience a bug, or suggest an interesting improvement. I create a Jira issue if this is new, or I edit a former Jira issue if this is already known.

Right now, I only add a new comment each time, to record who and when.

The customers don't have access to Jira and never will.

At the end, I would like to be able to :

- find all customers who experience an issue
- find all issued experienced by a customer
- order issues by number of customer who have experienced it

With my method I can do the first thing, but not the two others, which is really annoying when you need to get back to a customer to announce that things has been resolved or implemented.

---

Solution 1:
Create a custom text field with the customer name.

Solution 2:
Use tags to record the customer name.

Solution 3:
Continue to add comment on Jira issue.
And add the Jira Issue ID directly in our CRM.

Each look a little bit messy and I'm not sure I will be able to do the 3 things I want.

Do you have any suggestions or best practice to do this ?
It seems to me that this should be pretty standard...

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered creating a "Customer Issues" project? Then when you create one of these issues you can have a field indicating which client(s) experienced it. Also, having a selectable list of customers will give you more reliable data than a text field, since if one of your clients is say, the state of Illinois, then someone may type "Illinois" or "State of Illinois" or "Illinois Government", etc. resulting in three different client names.

For any client issue that you end up deciding to fix, you can create an issue on the corresponding development project and link the two. Then you can get the three reports you were looking for

- Look at the list of customers on the client issue
- Do a search for `Project = CI AND Customer = ???`
- This is trickier. There isn't native support in JQL for finding the count of a field, so you'd probably have to create a scripted field using a plugin such as Script Runner that stores the count of items selected in the Customer field, then run a query against that. Not ideal, but JQL has some limitations, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Let's expand your requirements:

> find all customers who experience an issue

you need identity of customers to associate with the issue

> find all issued experienced by a customer

you need vertical association of customer with all related issues

> order issues by number of customer who have experienced it

you need aggregated sum of complaint customers per issue (group by issue, order by occurence)

If you like to keep your current process (adding comments to current issue), you can create a trigger for "Issue Commented" Event to record customers and feed a custom field similar to tags but you need to record each customer name exactly same (JohnDoe not John_Doe) OR this trigger can associate this issue with an existing customer footprint issue or create a new issue like new customer footprint - issue type and/or automatically associate this customer footprint with the issue, which are messy :-)

Better way is to create another project for customer issues or creating a new issue type for customers that has customer info, and linking these issues with exact issue in order to maintain transparency. You will be able to list and monitor issues, and respond back to your customers easily when exact issue is closed. This will satisfy all of your requirements, thanks to JQL :-)